# makefile get error : multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: makefile, bison, flex-lexer

I run `make` and get : `makefile:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`

I tried to rewrite :(
this is the makefile :

`all: clean flex scanner.flex bison -d parser.ypp g++ -o hw3 *.c *.cpp clean: rm -f lex.yy.c rm -f parser.tab.*pp rm -f hw3`

Answer (score 2):

The makefile you present has been mangled by having multiple lines collapsed into one.  I think that must be what you're actually trying to use, not merely an artifact of posting the question here, because that's consistent with the error message you report.  It looks like the intended, uncollapsed form would be this:

```
all: clean
    flex scanner.flex
    bison -d parser.ypp
    g++ -o hw3 *.c *.cpp

clean:
    rm -f lex.yy.c
    rm -f parser.tab.*pp
    rm -f hw3
```

Note that the indentation is with tabs, not spaces. This matters to `make`.